# The calendar is black on pageload but works of i click the next day

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar that is loaded in a div in a webpage. when the page loads, it has all its buttons but there are no grid to display the days, its just no space.

however, if i click next/prev or any of the buttons the calendar is show properly.

ive tried to spesificly load today:

```
$('#userboxCalendar').fullCalendar('today');
```

but it does not work :( any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript is loading before the css script.... try moving your script to the bottom of the page and css load to the top... or  make it inline on the page.... also if you are using ajax to load the div you could use the callback done loading to re-render as stated here and above.  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/

I loaded one in colorbox... and used the colorbox done loading and it works great... also works when loading google maps... map.render or something like that...

Comment: I am using colorbox and I am having the same issue. once I re-size the browser or click on FC buttons It works.. can you please help..thanks!

Answer (score -1):

i can't say why it is happening (might be due to dynamically changing the dom or css) but you can force the calendar to render with this method:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/

Comment: I have the same problem. If I only change the size of window, or click Today or arrows the calendar render. I user the render method but it didn't change nothing. Can you help me please? How can I fix this problem! Thanks a lot.